# What is the Radio button symbol for Microsoft Word that Acrobat understands when converting to PDF form

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Someone has sent me a survey they had created in Microsoft Word, with a bunch of questions that need to be converted into a PDF form. I have no problem creating textboxes or checkboxes by using underscores and square symbols which the Acrobat interprets correctly when I go to "Convert to PDF Form". However I have not had the same success with *Radio Buttons*, I've tried using circles, "o", and "0" as symbols but nothing has worked...Acrobat does not convert these to a Radio Button

Answer (score 0):

I can't help directly with your question, but it may not be easy for this kind of automated process to create radio buttons correctly.

Within each group, radio buttons need to be mutually exclusively selectable. You would need some way of telling the automated process which buttons are in which groups for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To get radio buttons in a PDF, create Option buttons in Word. It requires that you first enable the Developer tab to the Ribbon bar.

Refer to http://personal.psu.edu/yxc165/blogs/comm_-_support/2010/08/adding-raido-buttons-to-ms-word-2010.html